# Session Persistence in Jboss cluster

Tags: session, jboss7.x

Which is the better option for session persistence in jboss cluster - memcached or DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [infinispan](http://infinispan.org)? It is working very well with JBoss.